# Getting error 403 "forbidden" when trying to delete file from box

Tags: postman, box-api

I'm using postman to make my delete request to the box in order to delete a file. I'mm having a problem when executing the request because i keep getting the error 403 "forbidden"

```
{
    "status": 403,
    "code": "forbidden"
}
```

the access token that im working with is sufficent (when i try to make other requests with it it shows me the correct result)

Comment: Does it have the correct scope or privileges to delete items? It could be different from getting items or creating them.

Comment: I'm really not sure about that, do you know where i can find the privileges that i have ?. All i know is that the access token that i'm working with allow me to execute upload, search and create metadata requests.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the API documentation? It have multiple different options for different scope so it’s worth reading through that and understanding it.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did for all my requests (upload files, metadtata creation and search) and all of them work just fine, however i encoutered the problem with the deleating request and i don't know why.
This is the deleating request that i'm sending :
https://api.box.com/2.0/files/*****
Authorization: Bearer ****

Comment: Do you understand the way scopes work? Just because you have a valid token that doesn’t automatically mean you can do everything with it. You might be able to view something but deleting something is a completely different and permanent action. I’ve never used that API, i’m Just thinking logically about your problem.

Comment: I understand that a scope can give a set of capabilities. I only began reading about box api lately so i don't really get how to attribute a set of scopes to an app or a user.
So you think that my problem is that i don't have the privilege to dleete file is that right ? 
If so, can you show me how have that privilege please ?

Comment: It’s a possibility, not the only thing it could be. I have never used the API, like I said. Read through the documentation, practice, experiment, search the box community forum for similar problems, basic research etc. Cover all options available to you.